# How do I reference the value of a form input using JavaScript without submitting the form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Specifically, what I am trying to do is reference the value of a form box to use in a function, based on a radio button selection.

Here's the applicable code parts:

```
var salaryBox = document.forms[0].salary;

function getFedTax() {
    var fedTax = 0;
    var income = salaryBox.value;
    if (document.getElementById("single").checked) {
        if (income >= 8350) {
            fedTax = income * .10;
            messageElement.innerHTML = "Your federal tax amount is: " + fedTax;
        }
    }
}
```

This function is based on the first radio button (Single) being checked. If checked, and the salary box value is >= 8350, I want it to perform that calculation and display it in the messageElement section of the HTML.

Here's the full code on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3fqv2jwa/10/

Also, if anyone knows why my function getStateTax() in the code isn't displaying properly in the el.innerHTML, I would appreciate help with that as well!

Comment: So what exactly is going wrong? You should have one or more event listeners to do the calculation at an appropriate time. You'll need to cater for a partially complete form, and for changes.

Comment: The code either isn't working or isn't properly displaying in the messageElement.

Comment: Oh...derp. I added the event handlers and it appears to be working now.

One question: what event handler should I use for updating the drop-down list? "onchange" works well for the salary boxes, but choosing a different state from the drop down menu with the "onchange" event handler doesn't update properly.